# How can I select a date within a date-picker?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to select a date within a date picker but I don't know which method to use to make the date picker appear and then select the right date (not unavailable). Dates (number of the day) are changing every month.

[image: date_picker]

Comment: if you want a specific date  , you can just type it in the input ..u can probably make date picker appear by clicking or typing something in the input

Comment: @hretic it's a good point but here the input is not available :/

Comment: what do you mean by `not available` ? i can see it in the picture you posted

Comment: It's not possible to write into the input. If we click on it, the date picker appears

Comment: @MorganBvt did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

@Morgan yes you can send date value in the date picker 
In my case I have to datepicker start date and end date 
When I send the date in the start date it actually appends to 
The current date which by default appears in the box 
When I send the date in the end date box it actually accept 
That date and save as well